# Error while running Mvc Music store

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

First of all I am sorry to ask a stupid question, this is because I am novice in ASP.NET.
I am following asp.net MVC music store tutorial and here is what I have made:

```
 namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var genre = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre{ Name = "Disco"},
                new Genre{ Name = "Jazz"},
                new Genre{ Name = "Rock"}
            };
            return View();
        }
```

............

Genre Class

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}

    }
}
```

Album Class

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Store";
}

<h2>Browse Genre</h2>

<p>Select from @Model.Count() genres:</p>
<ul>
    @foreach (var genre in Model)
    {
        <li>@genre.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Error I am getting is this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happen sis because you haven't passed any model to the view. So in the `Index` action instead of:

```
return View();
```

do:

```
return View(genre);
```

You have defined the `genre` list variable but you need to pass it to the view.

Comment: +1 Thanks ! Such a fool I am. I don't know how will I learn MVC if I make such mistakes. Thanks again for quick response. I will take 9 more min SO will allow me to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Is ASP.NET MVC Music store is the right way to learn asp.net MVC or should I follow other tutorial ?

Comment: @Chris, the Music Store is a good starting point. Also you shouldn't worry about such mistakes. Everybody does mistakes. People do mistakes all the time and it's better if they are made during the learning process rather than when dealing with some real world problems. So don't hesitate to ask if you encounter difficulties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the motivation.